# react router single component with both private & public nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am on react-router v5
My jsx:

```js
<Home>
    { auth.user && <Sidebar /> }
    <Main />
</Home>
```

I have following two routes:

```
"\" => public route 
"\folder\:topicId" => private route
```

I added these routes inside `<Sidebar />` component.
Depending on these routes, i want to update `<Main />` component.

Orginally, i had a top-level switch inside `<App />` for this purpose:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home/> // displays public content inside <Main />
  </Route>
  <PrivateRoute path="/folder">
    <Home/> // display private content inside <Main /> depending on topic
  </PrivateRoute>
</Switch>
```

but this caused re-rendering of entire `<Home/>` while navigating from `"/"` to `"/folder/:topicId"` and vice-versa.

So, I thought of adding switch inside `<Home />`, but then how can i make `"/folder"` a private route?

What shall i do to switch between these routes, while update only the `<Main />` component?

Comment: Why 2 routes are rendering the <Home /> ?

Comment: @Shyam because I don't know how to render the top-level private route to update the inner `<Main />`

Comment: You can do this inside your Home . Instead of rendering <Main /> you can render <PrivateRoute path="/folder" component={Main} />

Comment: @Shyam and what to do when the url is "/" ? <Main /> should be displayed either ways.

Comment: @Shyam in the top-level <App /> switch, if there is only "/" route, then it renders nested private route "/folder/:topicId" instead of redirecting to login